# Oracle SQL Developer Regex expressions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am not an expert in regex expression and looking for help. Thanks in advance

I want to extract a formatted substring from a description column. Sample below

FROM

```
my testing on 456897 - Carol M. Smith, Ph.D. 
my testing on 435670 - Ms. Paulina M. Hall
my testing on 980765 - Mr. John Smith
my testing on 14567 - Mrs. Lena C. Callum
my testing on 555777 - Dr. Paul F. Fairlake
234567 - Mr. Ryan M. Palmer, Sr.
123456 - Joyce R. Hilton, Ph.D.
```

TO

```
my testing on 456897 - C.Smith 
my testing on 435670 - Ms. P. Hall
my testing on 980765 - Mr. J. Smith
my testing on 14567 - Mrs. L. Callum
my testing on 555777 - Dr. P. Fairlake
234567 - Mr. R. Palmer
123456 - J. Hilton
```

My query works for the first and last record. However, the ones with titles are a little bit complicated.

For the records with title, I need to keep the title the first name and the Last Name initial.

```
SELECT description,
       CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(description, '(Mr\.|Ms\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.)') THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '(Ms\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z]\.)')
           WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(description, '(Mr\.|Ms\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.)')  THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '(\w)\w*\W+(\w)\w*\W+(\w+),.*', '\1. \3')
           ELSE 'some other validation needed'
       END AS order_regex
       from mytable;
```

Again thanks for any suggestion.
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
select
  t1.*
 ,regexp_replace(
     t1.description
    ,'([^-]+)-\s*((Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr)[.]\s*)?(\w)\w*(\s[a-zA-Z.]*)*\s(\w+)(,.*|$)'
    ,'\1- \2\4. \6'
    ) subs
from t1
```

Short description of this regular expression:

1. `([^-]+)-` - finds the first part of a substring ending with `-` (subexpression #1)
2. `\s*` - any number of space characters
3. `((Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr)[.]\s*)?` - checks if Mr.|Ms.|Mrs.|Dr. exists and returns as subexpression #2
4. `(\w)\w*` - finds a name and returns the first letter as subexpression $3
5. `(\s[a-zA-Z.]*)*` - any number of words between the first name and the last name (subexpression #4)
6. `\s(\w+)(,.*|$)` - finds last name (i.e., the last word before ',' or the end of string) and returns as subexpression #5.

Full test case:

```
with t1 as (
select 'my testing on 456897 - Carol M. Smith, Ph.D. ' description from dual union all
select 'my testing on 435670 - Ms. Paulina M. Hall' from dual union all
select 'my testing on 980765 - Mr. John Smith' from dual union all
select 'my testing on 14567 - Mrs. Lena C. Callum' from dual union all
select 'my testing on 555777 - Dr. Paul F. Fairlake' from dual union all
select '234567 - Mr. Ryan M. Palmer, Sr.' from dual union all
select '123456 - Joyce R. Hilton, Ph.D.' from dual  
)
select
  t1.*
 ,regexp_replace(
     t1.description
    ,'([^-]+)-\s*((Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr)[.]\s*)?(\w)\w*(\s[a-zA-Z.]*)*\s(\w+)(,.*|$)'
    ,'\1- \2\4. \6'
    ) subs
from t1;
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/HNHHzGR4

Comment: Thanks. works perfectly! I've been trying to modify the Regex expression to include hyphenated last name like Smith-Jones, but not luck. i.e my testing on 456789- Mrs. Kyra Smith-Jones. Can you please assist? Thanks

Comment: @juniorR just replace `\s(\w+)(,.*|$)` in the end to `\s([a-zA-Z-]+)(,.*|$)`

Answer (score 0):

For this exact example you can use something like this:

```sql
select
  description,
       CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(description, '(Mr\.|Ms\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.)') THEN 
              REGEXP_REPLACE(description,  '(Ms\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.) ([A-Z])[a-zA-Z. ]+ ([A-Za-z]+)', '\1 \2. \3')
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(description, ', (Ph\.D\.|Sr\.)')  THEN 
              REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '([A-Z])[a-z]+ ([A-Z]\.)? ([A-Z][a-z]+), (Ph\.D\.|Sr\.)', '\1. \3')
           ELSE 'some other validation needed'
       END AS order_regex
from t1
```

Edit: a bit more generic towards multipart names:

```sql
select
  description,
       CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(description, '(Mr\.|Ms\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.)') THEN 
              REGEXP_REPLACE(description,  '(Ms\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Dr\.) ([A-Z])[a-zA-Z. ]+ ([A-Za-z]+)', '\1 \2. \3')
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(description, ', (Ph\.D\.|Sr\.)')  THEN 
              REGEXP_REPLACE(description, '([A-Z])[a-zA-Z. ]* ([A-Z][a-z]+), (Ph\.D\.|Sr\.)', '\1. \2')
           ELSE 'some other validation needed'
       END AS order_regex
from t1
```

Demo <del>[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vK3VknUx)</del> [v2](https://dbfiddle.uk/836peoCm)

But generally, names are quite hard to parse, and I'm afraid simple set of regexes wouldn't work.